# Multi-PC (worldwide) login system

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, authentication

I need to create a worldwide login system for my game launcher. (Worldwide meaning you can access it from any PC with an internet connection). I tried using an SQL database, but I tried it on a different PC but it didn't work (I am assuming because the SQL Database is a local file on my PC). Does anyone have any **free** solution for this? I can turn my PC into a server if needed, as it has good parts and I am not expecting many logins.

Many thanks,
ocmMelvin!

This is the SQL Database code if neccessary:

````
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from RealityCredentails where Email='" & EmailInput.Text & "' and Password='" & passwordInput.Text & "'", con)
        Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim localCredentials() As String
        sda.Fill(dt)```
````

Comment: Watch out for sql injection: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp . Sounds like you need a database hosted with a hosting provider.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons I did not want to use an SQL database.

Comment: Which part? The hosting or the sql injection? Sql injection would be a risk on any database within reason.

Comment: Just not using an SQL database at all. I was hoping there would be another database which I could host from my PC.

Comment: Like for example, a database stored on my PC which the users could access and compare credentials, to sign in.

Comment: You're not going to want people authenticating to your database from their computers.  What you probably need is a middle tier, an API site that serves as the middle man between your game client and the database server.  Your game would make a REST request to the web-site and the web-site would handle talking to the database and return data.  This has a benefit of being able to scale out the API sites if eventually needed as well as potentially adding things like a Redis server without the game client having to change. This means you can also update the API logic without a game client update.

Comment: How many users are we talking about?  I have 2 suggestions, but which one is better depends on the number of users.

Comment: If you want longevity and scalability, I would suggest you look into Azure Table storage (it's not SQL, and has a free tier) with Azure Durable Function Orchestrator.  I do have a couple of ideas for something much simpler you could do locally, though, once I know how many users you're talking about.

Comment: As a start, I'm thinking less than about 10 members logging in an hour. I also don't want the database held locally, as wouldn't that allow users to view tables and see others credentials. I need to access the database from the launcher, not the client.

Comment: First, since all you're doing is authenticating users, there are free solutions designed for just that.  Look at OpenLDAP and see what you think.  If you'd rather write your own REST API, I can tell you how to do the JSON part of it for handling the data (no SQL server involved).  You're on your own for the API, but there are plenty of examples around.

Comment: This is just what I needed, thank you so much!